# Execute JQuery from click in GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I'm trying to adjust the height of the background div I'm using for a modal window on my page.
The modal is displayed off a click in a GridView and should set the height of the modal background div to the same height as the `body` element.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Booking Agent" SortExpression="clientname">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSMSDriver" Text='<%# Eval("clientname") %>'
        CommandName="SMSClient" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("clientid") %>' CssClass="callModal"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".callModal").click(function() {
        $(".modalbg").css("height", $("body").css("height"));
    });
</script>
```

Presumably, this should set the modal background to the same height of ALL the content on the page, regardless of scrolling.

At least, this is what I'm trying to accomplish. The thing is though, the height of the `modalbg` div keeps getting set to 0.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
$(".callModal").click(function() {
    var bodyHeight = $("body").outerHeight();
    $(".modalbg").css("height", bodyHeight);
});
```